# Reading all files from an folder

Tags: c#, file, uwp, path

So I have a folder named Documents. In this folder there are pdf files like for example 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf

Now I want to read all those files from the folder and get specific information. I need the

full filename: "1.pdf"

extension: "pdf"

id: "1"

modified date attribute: "10.10.2018"

Now my idea was to create a class something like:

```
public class FileElements
{
    string filename;
    string extension;
    string id;
    string modifiedDate;
}
```

Then I would create a list of the `FileElements` class.

I guess then I have to get the path of the folder and go trough the files with a `foreach` method.

Now my Problem is, I dont know how to go trough the folder and how I can get the specific information.

*edit*

It is not necessarily a .pdf file. It could be mixed up.

Comment: Is the directory part of your private app storage or part of the user's file system?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.IO;

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.pdf");
```

You should be able to get most of the information that you need from [FileInfo](http://FileInfo),
You will not need to use the custom object of FileElements contains everything you need, Or gives you a way to get it

Comment: You may want to point out that by leveraging `FileInfo` you do not require a plain old C# object like the OP has defined, since all the information in that model exists within `FileInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   List<FileElements> lstFileElements = new List<FileElements>;
   foreach(string pdfFile in Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
   {
      FileElements temp = New FileElements();
      temp.filename = Path.GetFileName(pdfFile);
      temp.extension = Path.GetExtension(pdfFile);
      //etc...
      lstFileElements.Add(temp);
   }
```

Something like this?